# Query Sequelize related models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following models:

Address, User and Invitation.

My relations between them are like this:

```
  User.belongsTo(address)

  Invitation.belongsTo(user, { as: 'userRequest', foreignKey: 'userRequestId'});
  Invitation.belongsTo(user, { as: 'userInvited', foreignKey: 'userInvitedId'});
```

I want to do the following query:

```
var filterAddress = {model: address,
        attributes: [...]
      }

invitation.findAll({
include: [
  {
    model: user,
    as: 'userRequest',
    include: [
      filterAddress,
    ]
  },
  {
    model: user,
    as: 'userInvited',
    include: [
      filterAddress,
    ]
  },
],
```

})

But it returns me the Not unique table/alias: 'userInvited->address.

How can I fixed it ? I have searched also including an alias in the model of User for addres but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for both of the relation -

```
Invitation.belongsTo(User, {
                foreignKey : {
                    name : "userRequestId"
                },
                as : 'UserRequest'
            });
```

Comment: Can you share model definition of User and Invitation?

Answer (score 0):

User.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
var User= sequelize.define('user', {
 id: {
   allowNull: false,
   autoIncrement: true,
   primaryKey: true,
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER
 },
 .........
 },{
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
 });
  User.associate = function(models) {
  User.belongsTo(models.address);
  .......
};
 return User;
```

};

Invitation.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
var Invitation = sequelize.define('invitation', {
 id: {
   allowNull: false,
   autoIncrement: true,
   primaryKey: true,
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER
 },
 status: {
   type: DataTypes.ENUM('Waiting', 'Accept','Cancel') ,
   notNull: true      
 },
 userRequestId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  references: {
    model: 'user',
    key: 'id'
  },
` },
 userInvitedId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  references: {
    model: 'user',
    key: 'id'
  },
 }
},{
 timestamps: false,
 freezeTableName: true,
 });
Invitation.associate = function(models) {
  Invitation.belongsTo(models.user, { as: 'userRequest', foreignKey: 
  'userRequestId'});
  Invitation.belongsTo(models.user, { as: 'userInvited', foreignKey: 
 'userInvitedId'});
  };
return Invitation;
};
```